# Visual Studio 2013 and SSRS: The CONCAT function requires two arguments

Tags: visual-studio, t-sql, reporting-services

My query works fine in SQL Server Management Studio 2014 but when I put the query into SSRS in Visual Studio 2013, I get an error that says the CONCAT function requires two arguments. My code:

```
SELECT a.identityID, 
          { fn CONCAT(a.firstName, ' ', SUBSTRING(a.middleName, 1, 1), ' ', a.lastName, a.suffix) } AS 'Name1', 
          { fn CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) } AS 'Name2', 
          { fn CONCAT(d.number, ' ',d.prefix, ' ', d.street, ' ', d.tag, ' ', d.apt, ' ', d.city, ' ', d.state, ' ', d.zip) } AS 'Address'
    FROM person AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN identityOther AS b 
     ON a.identityID = b.identityID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN identity AS c 
     ON a.identityID = c.identityID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN address AS d 
     ON a.identityID = d.identityID
ORDER BY a.identityID
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? You should be able to just go concat(string1,string2,string3)

Comment: Have you tried using a concatenation operator instead? Like `+` in SQL Server or `||` in Oracle.

Comment: @StevenWhite if you use the + and one of the value is a null.. it makes the whole thing null!

Comment: Do all of the CONCATs fail if you run them independently in SSRS, or do some work? (Substitute hard coded values for two of the three fields, leaving one CONCAT in place, run the report, repeat as needed.)

Comment: @Harry That's what `ISNULL` is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you are using the `{fn }` ? It works for me when I remove them.

```
SELECT a.identityID, 
      CONCAT(a.firstName, ' ', SUBSTRING(a.middleName, 1, 1), ' ', a.lastName, a.suffix) AS 'Name1', 
      CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS 'Name2', 
      CONCAT(d.number, ' ',d.prefix, ' ', d.street, ' ', d.tag, ' ', d.apt, ' ', d.city, ' ', d.state, ' ', d.zip) AS 'Address'
FROM person AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN identityOther AS b 
 ON a.identityID = b.identityID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN identity AS c 
 ON a.identityID = c.identityID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN address AS d 
 ON a.identityID = d.identityID
ORDER BY a.identityID
```

Comment: not sure how the { fn } was added but like you, once it was taken out, it works. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. I think it’s something to do with ODBC... Feel free to mark as the answer to help others that may come across the same problem.